# How to asynchronously call aws lambda function using Python requests

Tags: python, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I know how to invoke AWS lambda function asynchronously using boto3 in python.

Here's the code I'm using:

```py
import boto3
import json

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda',
                             region_name='ap-northeast-2',
                             aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXX',
                             aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXX')
data = {"data1":"mydata"}

response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="my_lambda_function",
                                InvocationType="Event",         ###for asynchronous purposes
                                Payload=json.dumps(data)
                                )
```

but I want to invoke lambda asynchronously using requests instead of invoke method

ex):

```py
import requests
param= data = {"data1":"mydata"}
url = "https://xxxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/my_lambda_function)"
res = requests.get(url, params=param)
```

Should I implement the code for asynchronous calls myself? Is there a simple asynchronous way to call lambda requests?

Comment: I suppose I should ask *why* you need to do it over http rather than via the sdk? If you want to expose it via http you need to front it with API Gateway. There may be other options but API Gateway would be the natural method.

Comment: i am already using api gateway in aws . Access-key is required to use sdk. I want to have access to aws lambda without this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke a Lambda function through an HTTP request in two ways:

- [API Gateway integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html)
- [Lambda Function URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html)

Both will expose public HTTP endpoints, which you can call through a normal HTTP request. Beware that anyone on the internet will be able to invoke your function if they have the URL.

If you want the Lambda invocation by API Gateway to be asynchronous, follow these instructions: [Set up asynchronous invocation of the backend Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html).